# FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException

Tags: hadoop, hive

when ever i try to create a database on Hive I am getting the below error

```
hive> create database retail;
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Your metastore isn't running? You're missing a library in the classpath? Your hive-site.xml is misconfigured?

Answer (score 0):

I guss  it might be the hive_user's problem .you can check it  on the user table   to see permission.